# Substitute and change case for program variables

Tags: vim

I'm changing some notation in a few source code files.

In particular, variable names using the format

```
m_variable1
m_anothervariable
```

should be renamed and reformatted to

```
mVariable1
mAnotherVariable
```

That is, substitute *m_* with *m* and make the next character uppercase.

I know how todo simple substitutions, like

```
%s/m_/m/gc
```

using vim, but not sure how to add syntax for changing a char to uppercase in a substitute statement?

Comment: is it `m_anothervariable` or `m_another_variable` ? `m_anothervariable` will not be possible to transform to `mAnotherVariable` (well not generically) and is not valid snake_case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the first character of variable name uppercase, but I think you can hardly separate words from a consecutive string simply by built-in command.

I hope following command will help you:

```
:%s/\vm_(\w+)/m\u\1/g
```

**Explaination**

- `\v` enables the 'very magic' mode
- `\u` makes the first character of word after it uppercase
- `\1` references the first captured group

**Result**

```
mVariable1
mAnothervariable
```